# Fortran segmentation faults related to derived types

Tags: debugging, segmentation-fault, fortran, derived-types

I am having some serious trouble debugging a segmentation fault that occurs in my grid generation algorithm. Unfortunately, I can not provide a minimal working example. I guess if I could, I would be half-way to solving the problem myself. So basically I am hoping that somebody can share some thoughts on the problems I am facing.
Error message from the segmentation fault

```
forrtl: severe (174): SIGSEGV, segmentation fault occurred
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source            
gabel_v112         000000000054A346  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
gabel_v112         0000000000544C2C  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
gabel_v112         00000000005093DB  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
gabel_v112         000000000040103C  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
gabel_v112         000000000048E3F0  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
gabel_v112         0000000000400F17  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

Using traceback, the intel debugger and some old-fashioned write(*,*) I think I was able to narrow down the origin of the segmentation fault in the following subroutine:

```
SUBROUTINE create_type_12(l)

    use types
    use parameters
    use vars_and_data

    implicit none

    INTEGER(I4B), INTENT(IN) :: l
    INTEGER(I4B) :: b, nl, neighbor, n_11

    do b=1, nf(l)
        if(levels(l)%blocks(b)%state .EQ. state_interface_undecided) then
            n_11 = 0
            do nl=1, nlinks
                neighbor = levels(l)%blocks(b)%neighbors(nl)
                if(neighbor .GT. 0) then
                    if(levels(l)%blocks(neighbor)%state .EQ. state_fine1) n_11 = n_11 + 1
                end if
            end do
            if(n_11 .GT. 0) levels(l)%blocks(b)%state = state_fine2
        end if
    end do

END SUBROUTINE create_type_12
```

to be more precise, this line

```
if(levels(l)%blocks(neighbor)%state .EQ. state_fine1) n_11 = n_11 + 1
```

The data structure this subroutine operates on has been defined like this:

```
TYPE :: blockinfo
    INTEGER(I4B)                :: number
    INTEGER(I4B)                :: state
    INTEGER(I4B)                :: state_floodfill
    INTEGER(I4B)                :: state_proximity
    INTEGER(I4B), DIMENSION(26) :: neighbors
    INTEGER(I4B), DIMENSION(26) :: linktype
    INTEGER(I4B)                :: parent
    INTEGER(I4B), DIMENSION(8)  :: children
    INTEGER(I4B), DIMENSION(3)  :: pos
    INTEGER(I4B)                :: triangle_amount
    INTEGER(I4B)                :: triangle_ll
END TYPE blockinfo

TYPE :: block
    TYPE(blockinfo), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: blocks
END TYPE block

TYPE(block), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: levels
```

Now this is where the trouble starts. Normally I would compile with -check bounds to determine the origin of the segmentation fault. Unfortunetely with -check bounds the code runs normally and produces a valid result data set. Other compiler flags I used are -O3 -xSSE4.2 -ipo -static -assume buffered_io. Ifort compiler versions are 16.0.1 and 13.1.3. Verified the behavior on different machines.

Even worse, If I change some of the compile flags (e.g. omitting -xSSE4.2) the code runs fine. However, using -xSSE4.2 alone without any other optimization the code runs fine aswell. Switching to gfortran with 'similar' compile flags the code runs fine aswell.

Doing some more debugging I found out that the segmentation fault occurs when the variable b has the value 27388461. But to my surprise all values of levels(l)%blocks(27388461)%neighbors are within the size of blocks (which is 102883584 here), except for the negative ones of course. So I have no idea what could cause a segmentation fault here.

Long story short I have three questions, but any other hint is welcome:

1. is there anything obviously wrong with the way I am using the derived types here?
2. what could I do to further narrow down the origin of the segmentation fault?
3. and I really would not ask this if I had not run out of ideas several days ago: are there any known intel fortran compiler bugs related to derived types?

I know this type of "question" may not be ideally suited for stack overflow, but I hope someone could give me a useful hint.

**Edit**: The answer to question number 3 seems to be a "yes".
As Jim Dempsey in the Intel Fortran forum pointed out:

> Your blockinfo type has 70 integer(4) variables or 280 bytes. When the variable b has the value 27388461...
>   27388461 * 280 = 7668769080 = 0x1C9182138
>   IOW requires 33 bits. Some versions of IVF used the precision of the index variable to construct the byte offset of the element.

Using 8-byte integers as indices to the "blocktype" derived type seems to be a possible workaround. However, instead of changing the whole code to avoid a compiler bug that appears exist for several years now I would rather consider switching to a different compiler.

Comment: If debugging changes the behaviour, it is a good bet to think about a stack corruption. Check that you call all your subroutines and functions with the right argument types and array sizes. The problem can be somewhere else than where the crash happens.

Comment: should -gen-interfaces and -warn interfaces do the trick? I already tried that but to no avail.

Comment: Depends, if there is a call to an external procedure in a different file it may be undetected. If you want us to answer your problem, you will have to prepare a mcve http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: (1) All your types are dynamical -- do you _always_ check allocations?  Is everything initialized properly? Compilation-dependent errors like you report may expose bugs of these kinds.  Remember that the error may be seen far from where it's caused.  (2) Since you located the error, printing _everything_ about _all_ involved variables (sizes in the first place) should give you something (starting with `nf`). This  _severe (174) ... program attempted an invalid memory reference_ -- it happens somewhere.  Just thoughts, for better more code is needed, as Vladimir F says.